# Does /"1.0""stick""113.0"g,/ as part of CSV makes it invalid?

Tags: node.js, csv, specifications

I know that there is standard for CSV [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), but I couldn't find an answer to my question there.

Here is part of CSV, that "USDA National Nutrient Database" gives away:

```
"Nutrient data for:  01001,Butter, salted"
Nutrient,Unit,1Value per100g,"1.0""pat (1"" sq, 1/3"" high)""5.0"g,"1.0""tbsp""14.2"g,"1.0""cup""227.0"g,"1.0""stick""113.0"g,
Proximates
"Water",g,15.87,0.79,2.25,36.02,17.93
```

Library I am using to parse CSV is https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv and it doesn't like this `"g,` part. Is this a library bug, or invalid CSV?

Comment: Not really an answer, but: Even though there is an RFC, no one uses "Standardized CSV". Each application does it differently and thus you'll end up writing a custom parser per application :(

Answer (score 0):

The CSV data you provide does not conform to the point 4 of the [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) specification.

> The last field in the record must not be followed by a comma.

Which is the case in the second line of your data.